# c alternative to signal() + alarm()

Tags: c, fastcgi, lighttpd, signals, alarm

I'm building some FastCGI apps and it sort of bugs me that lighttpd doesn't kill them off after they've been idle, so I'm trying to have them close on their own.

I tried using

```
signal(SIGALRM, close);
alarm(300);
```

and having the close function execute exit(0), and that works almost well.

The problem is the close function is being called every time the main program loop runs though (I call alarm(300) each loop to reset it). I've read the man page for alarm() and it doesn't seem as though calling it multiple times with the same value should trip SIGALRM so I'm assuming Lighttpd is sending an alarm signal.

The big question! Is there a way to run a method after a specific interval, and have that interval be resettable without SIGALRM? I'd be nice if I could have multiple alarms as well.

Here's the whole app thus far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "fcgiapp.h"

FCGX_Stream     *in, *out, *err;
FCGX_ParamArray envp;
int calls = 0;

void print(char*, ...);
void close();

int main(void)
{
        // If I'm not used for five minutes, leave
        signal(SIGALRM, close);

        int reqCount = 0;

        while (FCGX_Accept(&in, &out, &err, &envp) >= 0)
        {
                print("Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");

                int i = 0;
                char **elements = envp;
                print("Environment:\n");
                while (elements[i])
                        print("\t%s\n", elements[i++]);

                print("\n\nDone. Have served %d requests", ++reqCount);
                print("\nFor some reason, close was called %d times", calls);

                alarm(300);
        }

        return 0;
}

void print(char *strFormat, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, strFormat);
        FCGX_VFPrintF(out, strFormat, args);
        va_end(args);
}

void close()
{
        calls++;
//      exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The superhack solution would be to have a counter inside the main loop and a counter in the handler and if the counter in the handler is larger than the one in the loop, exit.

I don't like superhack solutions.

Comment: Well, it's definite that SOMETHING is calling SIGALRM other than my code or FastCGI. I've removed the signal() call from my app and grepped through all of the FastCGI source code (they use USR1 and the IO signal, but that's it). Next step is to look through Lighttpd source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is: add a thread so that you can remove signal and alarm, and sync the thread and your main code (main thread).

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use POSIX timers. Timers do not have to use signals. You have a choice between not notifying at all, raising a signal, or running a function as a new thread (which I would do as it will not interfere with fastcgi).

Make sure you include `<signal.h>` and `<time.h>`, and link with `-lrt`

First, I'd fill out your sigevent structure:

```
struct sigevent myTimerSignal = {
    .sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD,
    .sigev_notify_function = close //Make sure you change your function declaration to close(union sigval), you do not need to use the sigval unless you store data in your event too
};
```

Now create your timer:

```
timer_t myTimer;
if(timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &myTimerSignal, &myTimer)){
    //An error occurred, handle it
}
```

Lets arm it, it will call close() in a new thread in 300 seconds:

```
struct itimerspec timeUntilClose = {
    .it_value = {
        .tv_sec = 300 //300 seconds
    }
};

if(timer_settime(myTimer, 0, &timeUntilClose, NULL)){
    //Handle the error
}
```

Now, you should have a timer ready to stop the program after 300 seconds. I know I may be late, but I hope this helps a future reader.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wrap the close function by another function which will first call sleep()?

Comment: But will that pause the whole application? I'll give it a shot

Comment: It does sort of hang when I try sleeping the interrupt as I believe it doesn't run in a thread. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: sleep implementation is based on SIGALRM so they are practically the same

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the `alarm` call is *seconds*, not minutes.  So you're asking to be woken up in 5 seconds after each time through the main loop.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was set to seconds for debugging and I forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to close all the file descriptors (including stdin and stdout). This should close the CGI instance if its idle.
- You can use `select()` with timeout to schedule instead of SIGALRM

Comment: stdin and stdout are a tad different in FastCGI. Also, stopping the app isn't the problem, killing it after it's been idle for five minutes is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that sort of avoids the point of the question, but it works. It will respond to only my application's signal events:

```
void close(int intSignal, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
        // For some stupid reason MY signal doesn't populate siginfo_t
        if (!info)
        {
                count++;
        }
}
```

If the siginfo struct is empty, that's because alarm() tripped it. If an outside process does it, siginfo_t.si_pid is populated with zero.

I still don't like this solution, but it works. Odd problem now is that doing an exit(0) doesn't close the application, though lighttpd thinks it's gone and spawns another. This means that now I've got rouge processes. `raise(SIGUSR1)` which is what is supposed to stop FastCGI scripts doesn't seem to do the trick either... hmmm...

Question still remains: How does one call asynchronous functions on an interval timer without the use of signals?